# How to create alert notification in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp

I'm using this plugin Full Calender to create some Events

https://github.com/curtisblack2004/CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin

I also added Cron Shell which send a message every week

My problem now I want for exemple every new event send a notification message 
by email also notify the user the event has been created 
which mean inside my EventController

more accurately in my add function

EventsController

```
public function add()
{
$event = $this->Events->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $event = $this->Events->patchEntity($event, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Events->save($event)) {
            //function I need here to send mail
            $this->Flash->success(__('The event has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The event could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set('eventTypes', $this->Events->EventTypes->find('list'));
    $this->set(compact('event'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['event']);
    $this->set('user_session', $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User'));
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('user');
}
```

index.ctp

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
              <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle info-number" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                <span class="badge bg-green">6</span>
              </a>
              <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list" role="menu">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your system need to check status in database for state change.

After your system create calendar event, you have to save that record in database. Basically, you have to request to server to get response. Now, you need response without request. This is the basic idea of notification.

- Bad idea is do check with time interval via ajax.
- Good idea may be using socket io (https://socket.io/) and Node.js

I believe you can't find **plug and play** plug-in for this.